# Present a new view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to click a button and then present a new view like `present modally` in UIKit
[image]

I have already seen "[How to present a new view using sheets](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets)", but I don't want to attach it to the main view as a modal sheet.

And I don't want to use `NavigationLink`, because I don't want a new view and old view have a navigation relationship.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Why you don't want to attach it to the main view as a modal sheet? It is a standard method even in `UIKit`. Do you have any special reason?

Comment: I try to explain my thoughts... If there is anything wrong, please correct me.

Comment: The Apps have 3 view,
1: Login Page
2: TableView Page
3: TableDetail Page,
TableView  page and TableDetail page is navigation relation.

After login will present to TableView page, TableView page has no any relationship with login page after login

Comment: So you need it to be `fullscreen` right?

Comment: ys! i want `fullscreen `

Comment: Ok I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970681/5623035). The accepted answer and other answers are not **making** it fullscreen, they just made it **visually look like it is**.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## To show a modal (iOS 13 style)

You just need a simple `sheet` with the ability to dismiss itself:

```
struct ModalView: View {
    @Binding var presentedAsModal: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("dismiss") { self.presentedAsModal = false }
    }
}
```

And present it like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentingModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") { self.presentingModal = true }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) { ModalView(presentedAsModal: self.$presentingModal) }
    }
}
```

<sub>**Note that** I passed the `presentingModal` to the modal so you can dismiss it from the modal itself, but you can get rid of it.</sub>

---

## To make it REALLY present `fullscreen` (Not just visually)

You need to access to the `ViewController`. So you need some helper containers and environment stuff:

```
struct ViewControllerHolder {
    weak var value: UIViewController?
}

struct ViewControllerKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: ViewControllerHolder {
        return ViewControllerHolder(value: UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)

    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        get { return self[ViewControllerKey.self].value }
        set { self[ViewControllerKey.self].value = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then you should use implement this extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func present<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
        toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = style
        toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
            builder()
                .environment(\.viewController, toPresent)
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "dismissModal"), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak toPresent] _ in
            toPresent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## Finally

you can make it `fullscreen` like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: UIViewController?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Login") {
            self.viewControllerHolder?.present(style: .fullScreen) {
                Text("Main") // Or any other view you like
// uncomment and add the below button for dismissing the modal
            // Button("Cancel") {
            //       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "dismissModal"), object: nil)
            //        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error at the environment property wrapper: Cannot convert value of type 'Environment<UIViewController?>' to specified type 'UIViewController'

Comment: It should be handled by default, but try adding `?` at the end of the line there. @jsbeginnerNodeJS

Comment: I get this error in the console: ```
Warning: Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7fafd2641d30> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7fafd2611bd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!```

Comment: how do you dismiss it?

Comment: @gabrielapittari `dismiss`

Comment: you have been granted the rank of master... Thanks!

Comment: When you use this method, will the previous view's memory automatically liberate itself?

Comment: sorry if i sound ignorant.. but why do we have to jump thorough so many hoops just to present a view modally?? doesn't it feel like a step backwards... SwiftUI just feels so incomplete.. what do you think? what am I missing here??

Comment: @gabrielapittari, I have modified the answer with dismiss implementation.

Comment: I tested the code above. Since the dismissModal notification observer is not removed from the NotificationCenter, the notification closure will be called multiple times after the second time of the modal showing.

Comment: Beware that with method #1 the user can dismiss the presented sheet by swiping it down. This is a problem if you need to do something when the user confirms or cancels what he's doing on the page.

Answer (score 30):

For iOS 14 and Xcode 12:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Modal with full screen") {
            self.isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: FullScreenModalView.init)
    }
}

struct FullScreenModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a modal view")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onTapGesture {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

See also: [How to present a full screen modal view using fullScreenCover()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover)

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** Below is not really like a "native modal", neither behave nor look&feel, but if anyone would need a custom transition of one view over other, making active only top one, the following approach might be helpful.

So, if you expect something like the following

[image: custom SwiftUI modal]

Here is a simple code for demo the approach (of corse animation & transition parameters can be changed by wish)

```
struct ModalView : View {
    @Binding var activeModal: Bool
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                    self.activeModal = false
                }
            }) {
                Text("Hide modal")
            }
            Text("Modal View")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @Binding var activeModal: Bool
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                    self.activeModal = true
                }
            }) {
                Text("Show modal")
            }
            Text("Main View")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct ModalContainer: View {
    @State var showingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MainView(activeModal: $showingModal)
                .allowsHitTesting(!showingModal)
                .disabled(showingModal)
            if showingModal {
                ModalView(activeModal: $showingModal)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Mojtaba Hosseini answer. Tested with `iOS 16.4`

```swift
struct PresentEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: PresentAction = .init()
}
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var present: PresentAction {
        get { self[PresentEnvironmentKey.self] }
    }
}
struct PresentAction {
    func callAsFunction<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(style: style, builder: builder)
    }
}
extension UIApplication {
    static func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared
            .connectedScenes.compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }.last
        
        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            return topController
        }
        return keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }
}
extension UIViewController {
    func present<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
        toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = style
        toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
            builder()
        )
        self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.present) var present
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("FullScreenCover") {
            present(style: .fullScreen) {
                YellowView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct YellowView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .onTapGesture {
                dismiss()
            }
    }
}
```

In case you need access to a topViewController from SwiftUI View:

```swift
 extension EnvironmentValues {
     var topViewController: UIViewController? {
         get { UIApplication.topViewController() }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one way - forward views. It's very straight forward.

```
        struct ChildView: View{
           private  let colors: [Color] = [.red, .yellow,.green,.white]
           @Binding var index : Int
           var body: some View {
           let next = (self.index+1)  % MyContainer.totalChildren
             return   ZStack{
                    colors[self.index  % colors.count]
                     Button("myNextView \(next)   ", action: {
                    withAnimation{
                        self.index = next
                    }
                    }
                )}.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing)  , removal:  .move(edge: .leading)  ))
            }
        }

        struct MyContainer: View {
            static var totalChildren = 10
            @State private var value: Int = 0
            var body: some View {
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0..<(Self.totalChildren) ) { index in
                            Group{
                            if    index == self.value {
                                ChildView(index:  self.$value)
                                }}
                            }
                }
                }
        }
```