# Navigation in a complex multiview app in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I am creating quite a complex Multiview SwiftUI app. Is there any way to create several separate files for each ContentView and navigate between them or do I have to put everything into the main ContentView file?

What I tried and looks the best for now is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

(...)
     
struct SomeOtherContentViewInAnotherFile: View {
            
            @State var isPresenting = false
            
        
        (...)
        
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
    VStack{
        
        (...)
                    
         Button("Go Back"){
                        isPresenting = true
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination:ContentView(), isActive: $isPresenting)
                    
                    }.padding() }
        }
        }
```

But it throws out the following error:

```
"Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
Insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>, '"
```

Can you help?

Comment: Here's an answer I posted some time ago for something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517430/how-to-present-a-view-without-embedding-it-into-a-current-navigation-flow-in-swi/67521700#67521700

Comment: Thank you @xTwisteDx I'll check it out tomorrow. I tried to use enums and cases before in this app, but didn't know they could let me switch between the classes inside different files

Comment: If you select your code in Xcode and do `ctrl-i`, you can format your code -- that will be very useful in keeping things readable

Comment: I tried to use your solution, @xTwisteDx, but after I copied and tried to arrange your code I got a bunch of errors.
Could you please try preparing that code for the case of this app?

I need 4 screens: 1 main and 3 subscreens. The main screen has only navigation buttons (and it works well for me). The subscreens would need one function but for the ability to come back to the main screen from them.

Comment: The purpose of my post is to provide a foundation for you to work off of. There should be little to no issues if you follow it closely. If you are running into issues it may be a concept that is too far advanced for your skillset. Perhaps try diagnosing each issue you face. The reality is that you'll need to learn to handle things that you don't understand in the dev world. That's our job, we're paid for our ability to find an answer, not for what we know.