# How to start a new navigation stack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building an IOS App and I have a flow that enables users to build and share a post. First they start on a home screen, where they select the media, then another screen to write the paragraph and another one to edit the media and so on. At the end they share the post and I want them to come back to the root view and start the whole flow all over again but without the ability to navigate back.

How do I achieve that? I could technically hack it by disabling the back button in the root view but that doesn't feel clean.

Ideally, I would need to delete the current navigation stack and start a new one when they navigate back to home. Is there a way to do that?

If not, what is the standard way of doing it?

Comment: I gave a good answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517430/how-to-present-a-view-without-embedding-it-into-a-current-navigation-flow-in-swi/67521700#67521700 It should get you going.