# How do I connect screens to my main app page?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using Xcode version 15.0.1

This is what my main file looks like:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CarpoolyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have a separate folder outside of the main file called Screens. In the Screens folder I have a file called OnboardingviewController. I want to connect that file to my main file.
This is what said file looks like:

```
import UIKit

class OnboardingViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

How do I connect it to my main file?

Comment: Why are you mixing SwiftUI and UIKit?

Comment: Plenty of options, please provide tell us what exactly you want to achieve. So, you have a root SwiftUI view represented by `ContentView` and you want to show `OnboardingViewController` from there. How exactly you want it to look? Stack-based navigation and push? A tab bar? Modal presentation Something else?

Comment: I want to have a launch page(content view) and from that have a scroll bar that will have buttons to take you to various pages. How do I connect those pages to the main file while still displaying content view as the launch page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a UIViewController within SwiftUI, you can use the UIViewControllerRepresentable protocol. Here's a simple example:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct OnboardingViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        // Create and return your existing UIViewController here
        return OnboardingViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the UIViewController if needed
    }
}



struct OnboardingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            OnboardingViewControllerRepresentable()
                .navigationBarTitle("UIKit in SwiftUI")
        }
    }
}
```

And don’t forget to use OnboardingView in @main instead of ContentView

Comment: Wait i also want to display the ContentView. My idea for the app is that it will have a launch page(ContentView) and then from the launch page there will be buttons that can take you to other pages of the app, eg:OnboardingViewController. How do I connect the other pages to my main app file?

Comment: Oh , got you . You can achieve this by configuring navigation in your ContentView . You have to create Buttons in ContentView that redirect to another view. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958858/present-a-new-view-in-swiftui) @mojtaba-hosseini explained  about it. Feel free to ask any other questions)