# Linking a SwiftUI Button to a view controller in Xcode 12 / Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The expected result is the main menu to handoff to the other .swift file / view controller. I do not want a back button or any other functions only top hand off to a separate part of the app.

This is the Main Screen currently.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct FileView: View {

//Telling aray i want items 175 wide at least

let layout = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 175))
    ]
@State var date = Date()

var body: some View {
  
    
    ///Top Bar layout
    

            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image("Home")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(30), height: CGFloat(30), alignment: .leading)
                    }).padding(.leading, CGFloat(20))
                    .padding(.top, 15)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }

                HStack {
                    Text("DAILYMENU")
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top, 15)
                }

            }

    
    
    ///Setup DAILYMENU FEED LINE

    
    HStack{
        Text("DAILYMENU")
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .padding(.top, 100.0)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
        Spacer()
    }
    
        
    ///Setup Welcome messages
    
    

    HStack{
        Text(greeting())
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .padding(.leading, 20.0)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Menu"))
        Spacer()
        
        Text("...")
            .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }

    
    
    /// Setup navigation home
    
    
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 5) {
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("STOREMENU")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            
         //Add correct images Direction and Contact us
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Button action")
    }) {
                Image("DAILYMENU")
            }
            
            .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
            .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)

            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 2.5)
        .padding(.vertical, 2.5)
    }

var timeFormat: DateFormatter{
    let formatter = DateFormatter(); formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    return formatter
}

func timeString(date: Date) -> String {
    let time = timeFormat.string(from: date)
    return time
}

var updateTimer: Timer{
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in self.date = Date() })
}

func greeting() -> String{
    var greet = ""
    greet = ""
    
    //sleep is important
    let sleepMidNight = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 1, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)!
    let sleepNightEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 4, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)!
    
    //good morning
    let morningStart = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 9, minute: 00, second: 0, of: date)
    let morningEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 11, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)!
    
    //good afternoon
    let noonStart = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 11, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)!
    let noonEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 17, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)!
    
    //good evening
    let eveStart = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 17, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)!
    let eveEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 22, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)!
    
    //up late
    let nightStart = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 22, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)!
    let midNight24 = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 01, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)!
    
    //early riser
    let earlyRiser = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 01, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)
    let earlyRiserEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 06, minute: 00, second: 00, of: date)
    
    //way to start your day
    let wayToStart = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 06, minute: 01, second: 00, of: date)
    let wayToStartEnd = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 09, minute: 59, second: 59, of: date)
    
    
    if((date >= sleepMidNight)
        && (sleepNightEnd >= date)){
        greet = "Sleep is important!"
        
    }else if ((date >= morningStart!) && (morningEnd >= date)){
        greet = "Good Morning!"
        //would not run without ! after morningStart don't know why. Doesn't need it for others?
        
    }else if ((date >= noonStart) && (noonEnd >= date)){
        greet = "Good Afternoon!"
        
    }else if ((date >= eveStart) && (eveEnd >= date)){
    greet = "Good Evening!"
        
    }else if ((date >= nightStart) && (midNight24 >= date)){
        greet = "You're up late!"
        
    }else if ((date >= earlyRiser!) && (earlyRiserEnd! >= date)){
        greet = "Early Riser!"
        // had to do the ! on both Riser and End
        
    }else if ((date >= wayToStart!) && (wayToStartEnd! >= date)){
        greet = "What a way to start your day"
        // had to do the ! on both here too
    }
        
    return greet
}

}



    
struct File_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    FileView()
}
}
```

This is the second view the lets say first button needs to link to.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct VideoList: View {
@ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ViewModel
@State private var isRefreshing = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.videos.sorted { $0.id > $1.id}, id: \.id) { video in
            NavigationLink(
            destination: VideoDetails(viewModel: VideoDetails.ViewModel(video: video))) {
                VideoRow(video: video)
            }
        }
        .onPullToRefresh(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing, perform: {
            self.viewModel.fetchVideos()
        })
        .onReceive(viewModel.$videos, perform: { _ in
            self.isRefreshing = false
        })
        .navigationBarTitle(viewModel.navigationBarTitle)
    }
    .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchVideos)
}
}

#if DEBUG
struct VideoList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VideoList(viewModel: .init())
    }
}
}
#endif
```

UIKit made this easy as you only needed to setup a UB outlet and link it to the view... swiftUI seems to make it impossible to do this.i keep seeing examples to where I have to implement it in the same .swift however that breaks the view model connection in the correct .swift file which means the code becomes messy and unsorted.

thus either I'm implementing this wrong or something is causing conflicts with this style of implemention (example provided by @pawello2222).

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isLinkActive = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Button("Go to...") {
                // activate link programatically
                self.isLinkActive = true
            }
        }
        // hide navigation bar
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        )
    }
}
}

struct SecondView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    Button("Go back") {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
}
```

Comment: I should just be able to call VideoList() but that doesn't work here

Comment: Um this isn't anything about notifications... @dfd

Comment: Um, it sounds to me like you wish to *communicate* UI actions between SwiftUI and UIKit, right? As I tried to say in my first comment, I found `Combine` to be lacking a year ago - particularly when telling SwiftUI that a UIKit button tap happened. but, um, while you asked about telling UIKit about a SwiftUI action (and I hope that 12 months improved things), one thing that should work is Notifications. Just trying to help....

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714964/1630618) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @vacawamathe problem is that you have to start with a model view not SwiftUI as you can see the first view is built without any UIKit links

Comment: I also get the error "Insert 'viewModel: <#VideoList.ViewModel#>'" do it and it fails

Comment: my apologies vacawama I was not looking at @Liam's answer... how the above problem still applies sadly.

Comment: No I specified "handoff" meaning the SWiftUI view would no longer be active @dfd, essentially the video viewer was built in UIKit using SwiftUI instead of fully built in SwiftUI like it was supposed too. now I have to deal with this headache

Comment: With more respect (I didn't like your "um" - but I did feel your pain a year ago)? SwiftUI pretty much steers you to using a Model separate from the view. Or in Apple's case, Combine with all it's `@` where a change in the model means the views will respond. A year ago, how - using SwiftUI - could you (a) present a UIImagePickerController, (b) present a UIActivityController share sheet, or (c) present either an MTKView or a GLKView? Answer - you couldn't. Now let me present a *fourth* scenario. A child navigation controller presenting two table views (master/detail)....

Comment: 2/ .... where the master list can be edited. Just couldn't be done in SwiftUI. Maybe it can in iPadOS 14 with what they've done, but not with pure SwiftUI. So let's expand on that - basically you have a representable UIView with a button and want to let a View (or even a Combine model/class) that the user tapped on it. The best way (a year ago) that I found was Notifications. Yes, it was the **opposite** direction (UIKit > SwiftUI) than your question, but at a deep level (Swiftui model > UIKit) it should also work. Hopefully that explains what I really was thinking. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Sorry, last point. Back in the day, Microsoft was known to make things, including platforms, that nobody should really adopt until version 3.0. So please remember, SwiftUI is merely at 2.0! Were you using Swift since 1.0? Do you remember the **pain** of upgrading to 3.0 (and for some, 4.0)? My take for SwiftUI is (a) use it where you can, as this is where the puck is headed, but (b) do what you *have* to where it falls short.